# TS2345 Argument of type '(source: Observable<number>)=>Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am learning rxjs.
I follow the "RxJS Operators In-Depth - Part 1 - The Basics" example at
https://benlesh.com/posts/rxjs-operators-in-depth-part-1/

However, compiling the "Building a reusable operator with higher-order functions" source codes get the following errors.
How to fix it?

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

const multiply = (multiplier: number) => (source: Observable<number>) =>
  new Observable((subscriber) => {
    const subscription = source.subscribe({
      next: (value) => subscriber.next(multiplier * value),
      error: (err) => subscriber.error(err),
      complete: () => subscriber.complete(),
    });
    return () => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    };
  });
 
// Usage like so:
 
of(1, 2, 3, 4).pipe(multiply(2)).subscribe(console.log);
 
// Output:
// 2
// 4
// 6
// 8


const double = multiply(2);
 
const doubled = of(1, 2, 3, 4).pipe(double);
 

const doubledAgain = doubled.pipe(double);
 
doubledAgain.subscribe(console.log);
 
// Output:
// 4
// 8
// 12
// 16
```

```
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:45:39 - error TS2345: Argument of type '(source: Observable<number>) => Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>'.
  Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
    Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<number>'.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'.

45     const doubledAgain = doubled.pipe(double);
```

versions:
rxjs: ~7.8.0
typescript: ~5.0.2
angular/compiler: ^16.0.0

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

//https://benlesh.com/posts/rxjs-operators-in-depth-part-1/

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'benlesh';

  test() {
    console.log('test');
 
    const multiply = (multiplier: number) => (source: Observable<number>) =>
      new Observable((subscriber) => {
        const subscription = source.subscribe({
          next: (value) => subscriber.next(multiplier * value),
          error: (err) => subscriber.error(err),
          complete: () => subscriber.complete(),
        });
        return () => {
          subscription.unsubscribe();
        };
      });
     
    // Usage like so:
     
    of(1, 2, 3, 4).pipe(multiply(2)).subscribe(console.log);
     
    // Output:
    // 2
    // 4
    // 6
    // 8


    const double = multiply(2);
 
    const doubled = of(1, 2, 3, 4).pipe(double);
     

    const doubledAgain = doubled.pipe(double);
     
    doubledAgain.subscribe(console.log);
     
    // Output:
    // 4
    // 8
    // 12
    // 16 
  }

  constructor() {
    this.test();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code is worked, could you add more details or share your code on StackBlitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-nqghrj?file=index.ts

Comment: I add more details by putting the entire file app.component.ts . Compile error appear when running 'ng serve' on a terminal inside VSCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the number type for the new Observable (multiply)

```
 const multiply = (multiplier: number) => (source: Observable<number>) =>
      // was  'new Observable((subscriber) => {'
      // Declare the **number** type
      new Observable<number>((subscriber) => {
        const subscription = source.subscribe({
          next: (value) => subscriber.next(multiplier * value),
          error: (err) => subscriber.error(err),
          complete: () => subscriber.complete(),
        });
        return () => {
          subscription.unsubscribe();
        };
      });
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-csn4fp?file=src%2Fmain.ts